# Why Visual studio throws an error preventing adding of a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm using the same solutions to build a client and server app, client is with angular 8 and sever app is from **ASP .NET MVC core ( 3.0.100 )** i have tried to add a view from 
`right click on Shared -> add -> view` > once click on add its giving me this error preventing me from adding the view, Is there a way to fix this this?

[image]

Comment: Clean and Rebuild your project/solution then try again

Comment: @GiddyNaya matter of fact i took the detour, updated visual studio 2019 to the latest update fixed the issue.